# Use executing user credentials in powershell

Tags: powershell, dsc

I'm trying to create an Azure DevOps pipeline to build and deploy DSC PowerShell scripts and configuration files.

One Configuration needs credentials as a parameter. How can I pass the credential of a service user, that is executing the script?

I tried

```
$credential = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials
```

but it does not work. The service account is not a domain user, just an local account. The credential class must be [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential].

Any suggestions?

Comment: I guess you want to use the credentials of the computer account which SAM account is usual the ComputerName  suffixed with a dollar (e.g. `PC001$`)

Comment: No, in this case I want to use the account of a service user account. There is a service running in the background and executing Powershell scripts.